# how to notify that the maxlength is overflowing

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qt-signals

Is there a way to connect a signal before executing a default handler? I'm looking for a way to execute my function prior to QLineEdit::textChanged signal to execute notification about maximum length limit.

GTK+ has connect_before(), connect() and connect_after(). Is there something similar in Qt?

Comment: no, that does not exist in Qt.

Comment: I think you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what is your main goal?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I think I explained it clearly in the question - I'm looking for a way to give a user notification that he types character that will bring the text length over the max limit. And I'm looking for a way to do it in QT_VERSION < 5.12.

Comment: Can't you just connect the signal to a slot on class/scene initialisation? 

Comment: @Igor Sorry but if I do not understand then I have to ask. Do you want a signal that is emit when the number of characters exceeds the maxlength?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, what do you mean? I tried to connect to both textChanged and textEdited. The function fires after the default handler.

Comment: @eyllanesc, correct. and it has to work for qt 5.11 or below.

Comment: @eyllanesc, or maybe a virtual function that can be overriden and I can put that check there.

Comment: @Igor some feedback?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I was hoping not to do the key event, but I guess there is no other choice.

Comment: Why do not you like to overwrite the keyEvent? The signals are executed after something happens asynchronously, not before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyPressEvent method to issue the custom signal.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QLineEdit::QLineEdit;
signals:
    void maxLengthSignal();
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override{
        if(!event->text().isEmpty() && maxLength() == text().length())
            emit maxLengthSignal();
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    LineEdit w;
    QObject::connect(&w, &QLineEdit::textEdited, [](const QString & text){
        qDebug()<< text;
    });
    QObject::connect(&w, &LineEdit::maxLengthSignal, [](){
        qDebug()<< "maxLength signal";
    });
    w.setMaxLength(10);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: it works. The code can be written with the special signal in 5.12, but I'm not there yet. Thank you.

Comment: @Igor Edit your question so that it has more relation with my answer, something like: how to notify that the maxlength is overflowing? :-)

Comment: well the question was more broad - how to execute a signal handler in Qt before the default one. But we started discussing this specific issue. Now do I understand correctly that there is no general solution for the general problem? ;-)

Comment: @Igor Therefore, if you realize my solution is based on the comments and not on your question itself, I ask you to adapt it so that future readers will not be confused. :-)

Comment: well, its you fault we went into the detail discussion. ;-) But I edited the question.

Comment: I just realized that this code may not work if the user will try to paste some text from the Clipboard. Or will it? Especially if that happens thru the context menu and not a Ctrl+V shortcut. Any idea?